# Laravel как связать 2 таблицы для получения данных первой по id другой таблицы

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, laravel, проектирование

Всем привет. Допустим есть 2 таблицы - clients и payments.
У клиента может быть много платежей, потому тут в моделях у нас связь hasMany.
А как сделать так, чтобы по id клиента указанного в url (допустим url такой /get/client/{client}/payments, тут id клиента помещается в {client}) можно было получить все платежи конкретного клиента (ясно дело id характеризует конкретного клиента).
Прошу пожалуйста подсказать кто знает как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом вы же получаете клиента можете работать с платежами напрямую из метода например

```
public function payments(App\Models\Client $client) 
{
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'payload' => ['payments' => $client->payments]]);
}
```

Но это если у вас подобная связь

**clients:**

- id
- other

**payments**

- id
- client_id
- other

и соответственно в моделях

```
// App\Models\Client
public function payments(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Payments::class);
}

// App\Models\Payment
public function client(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

То собственно у вас уже есть все связи между платежами и клиентами то есть вы можете вытаскивать как платежи выбранного клиента так и клиента у конкретного платежа... Но ещё вы можете сделать скопу

```
// App\Models\Payment
public function scopeByClientId(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder, int $client_id): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
{
    return $builder->where('client_id', $client_id);
}
```

И теперь что бы получить платежи по id клиента достаточно попросить их **Payment::byClientId($client_id)->get()**

Comment: Payment::byClientId($client_id)->get() данный участок кода должен быть в контроллере? Не совсем понимаю как правильно передать id клиента из подобного url  /get/client/{client}/payments в метод чтобы по данному id и делалась выборка платежей в таблице платежей. По Вашему коду выборка идёт, но видимо где-то останавливается так как выходит пустой вывод, наверняка сам делаю что-то не так, вот вывод дебагера string(100) "select * from `payments` where `payments`.`id_client` is null and `payments`.`id_client` is not null" array(0) { } {"success":true,"payload":{"payments":[]}}

Comment: Там где хотите получить коллекцию платежей

Comment: Понял, спасибо!